# Why does rendering go wrong?

Tags: rendering, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, light

I am new in Blender and can't understand why rendering works like this. What can be wrong? I would be grateful for help.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blender has many Tabs in the properties panel as other panels do too. See the squares in the

As I see there are two options:

- Check the energy settings in the point light

[image: Energy setting]

- Delete and re-add the point light
- Use ambient occlusion

[image: Ambient occlusion]